# Import Class from a python package at runtime

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which will take `class` name a argument and import that class and perform some task.

```
  def search(**kwargs):
    """
    :return:
    """

    try:
        model = __import__('girvi.models', globals(), locals(),  kwargs['model_name'], -1)
       # Do some task
       return results
    except Exception:
        raise Exception('Model not found')
```

But thing is `model` has the class which is in `kwargs['model_name']` imported successfully but how do i access it. Please can someone help me.

Comment: It is not working... `'module' object is not callable`

Comment: I am sorry, I still couldn't understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: If i try this then it is working fine `print model.Customer.objects.all()` But then whats the point of all of this.

Comment: @user2217267: that's the point of it.

Comment: I want to write a function which will take `model name` and `query list` generated by `operator`as a argument. Then i will perform `filter` on that model. That can be generic for all of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
import importlib
import sys

def import_class(class_name, module_name = "girvi.models"):
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    class_object = getattr(module, class_name) # does not work for nested classes
    return class_object
```

According to `__import__` one should rather use `importlib.import_module`.